# pdfcrop does not crop pdflatex output correctly

Tags: pdftex, pdfcrop

I have a complicated table that uses the "array" package, which conflicts with other packages that I use, so I put the table into a separate document and ran pdflatex on it to get the table in a pdf file I can bring into the document using \includegraphics. That requires me to crop the pdf file from a full page to just the table. To avoid including the page number at the bottom of the page, I added \pagestyle{empty} and \pagenumbering(gobble} to the preamble, but even then, pdfcrop only cropped the top of the page; the margins and lower half of the page were untouched. With other pdf files pdfcrop has always worked perfectly. Does anyone know why it doesn't seem to work right with pdflatex output? And how to fix it?

Comment: if it works sometimes and sometimes not, then details are obviously important. So try to make a small but complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Following the hint at [pdfcrop fails to crop a PDF document with non-white background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22939/pdfcrop-fails-to-crop-a-pdf-document-with-non-white-background), I used

\usepackage[noheadfoot,nomarginpar,margin=1pt,paperwidth=5.925in,paperheight=4.35in]{geometry}

in the preamble to trim the page down to just fit the table, so my immediate problem is solved (without fixing pdfcrop).